# Rogue FaceBook Like

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention, facebook-pages, facebook-like

I've been getting a lot of news items in my Facebook news feed from things I've never heard of lately. I sent FB a bug report but they haven't responded. Today I found a way to look at all the pages that I had liked and out of 8 legit items, there were 30 or so that I've never heard of, some quite racy, the same ones in my news feed.

What's going on? How did they get there? I know I didn't press the like button for them because I've never even heard of them and rarely press 'like' anyways. Is this some kind of spam trend? How is this happening?

Comment: Between this and [your other post](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18206/how-to-leave-make-facebook-interests-blank), are you sure nobody got hold of your password?

Comment: I'm sure no one has got in.

Comment: Be careful of the sites olpix and list.funlolx that provides you funny pics or other.
They clickjack some like bouton of page when you click "Next" Bouton, you can see this when you copy the URL and go to Private navigation, a popup ask you to connect to your facebook account !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sites try to *Clickjack* facebook likes (see, e.g., [new facebook clickjacking attack](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2009/12/new-facebook-clickjagging-attack-in.html)) by hiding the *like* action behind an innocent-looking button.

Blocking scripts ([NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript) on Firefox, [NotScript](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn?hl=en) on [Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/8365/is-there-a-noscript-alternative-for-google-chrome)) can prevent some of these attacks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some links, sometimes acting as videos which cause the link to appear on your wall as a "like"

For example, you may see a video posted by a friend on your wall. Something that will tempt you to click on it, often NSFW stuff.

If you click on it, the video may or may not be played, but it will appear on your wall as a "like"

It manages to do this by javascript, though I dont really know how exactly