# How to leave/make Facebook interests blank?

Tags: facebook

When I got a Facebook account, I remember filling out the bare minimum necessary and I left all the fields like sports, music, etc blank. But, taking a look today, it looks like it's been populated with things I've never heard of.

QUESTION: How do I get rid of these items? I want the area to be completely blank.

That is, I don't want Jason Sissel in there. I have no idea who he is and didn't put him there in the first place.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **click on the item first** and then you can press 'DELETE' on your keyboard, or click the 'remove' link that appears.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's default "privacy" settings allow others to choose your likes and dislikes for you.  You can delete them but to prevent them from coming back you will need to change your privacy settings to not allow friends suggest likes.

Comment: Never heard of this setting.  Where is it?